# mySQL query for association table where ID is blank

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Let's say I have a posts table that has many comments (and a comment belongs to a user).

How would I show all posts where a particular user hasn't commented on?

Pretend I have a user in my database with an ID of 124;

```
select * from posts p left join comments c on p.id = c.post_id 
where c.id is null or c.user_id <> 124
```

But that doesn't seem right .. as what if the post has no comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the `user_id` from table `post` and not on table `comments` because there are some `user_id` that doesn't have any records yet on table `comments`.

```
SELECT  p.* 
FROM    posts p
        LEFT JOIN comments c
            ON p.id = c.post_id AND c.user_id = 124
WHERE   c.post_id IS NULL
```

Comment: My posts table doesn't have a user_id - I think you're missing the point? I'm trying to find all Posts where the user 124 hasn't commented on.

Comment: So if a post has no comments ... the post will appear in my query (Wasn't sure .. because the left join states that the c.user_id must equal 124??)

Comment: @Will, yes. Have you try executing it? here's the flow, the comments table was filter through `c.user_id = 124`, so only the post made by that user will be shown. But then you have used `LEFT JOIN`. So all the post on table `POST` will have null value on `c.post_id` if the user hasn't commented it yet. So to finally filter out, the query is added with `WHERE   c.post_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from posts p left join comments c 
on p.id = c.post_id 
where c.post_id is null and p.user_id = 124;
```

EDIT:

Please try this:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bd3f/4)

```
select * from posts p
where p.pid not in ( select c.pid
from comments c
where c.uid = 111)
;

| PID | PNAME |
---------------
|   3 |    p3 |
```

Comment: comments table will always have a user id as the commentator. So you can't check on user id in the comments table. So it has to come from `posts` =)

Comment: Read my response to JW - I'm trying to find all Posts where the user 124 hasn't commented on.

Comment: @Will I used my own sample data, and please take a look at it and comment :) If your table structure is different, then please share so I can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to use null as id for your question I would use something like this

```
select * from post p1 where not exists 
      (select 1 from comment c1 where c1.post_id = p1.id)
union
select * from post p2 where exists 
       (select 1 from comment c1 where c1.post_id = p1.id and c2.user_id <> 124)
```

Comment: why is it bad to use `NULL`?

Comment: Id should be unique. NULL is special value which is different from every value, NULL != 1 true, NULL != 'kfa' true, NULL != NULL true. That is why **is null** exists in sql. Because of this you can have two different values with Id NULL, and no way of knowing which is which. In this case it is bad id.Also it can lead to complication with join etc. NULL can be used again in some cases as ID, but there are lot of reasons why it shouldn't be done. And I don't know a lot reason as to way someone should use NULL as ID.